# Django. How to redirect to url with fragment identifier

Tags: django, django-urls

For example in some cases after POST or GET request I want to redirect user not only to specific page, but to a specific part of page. What would be better: implement this in Django(reconstruct redirect url?) or implement this in javascript?

Comment: "to a specific part of page" Are you referring to an anchor?

Comment: It's correct, I am talking about anchor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you want to do it in JS? If you're redirecting to a different page already, just add `#whatever` to the redirect URL to go direct to the anchor.

Comment: What if I use view names to get redirection url?

Comment: Django's reverse() function will return a unicode string, so you can just do:
reverse('my_vew_name') + '#whatever"