# Django: How to send user to ancor after POST

Tags: python, html, django, fragment-identifier

Supposed there is a long page with a form at the end. Now the user submits this form with invalid data and it gets rerendered.I don't want to have him scrolling all the way back down, so i want to send him to a

```
<a name="form"></a>
```

This is a related question: [Django. How to redirect to url with fragment identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053690/django-how-to-redirect-to-url-with-fragment-identifier) The difference is, that i am rerendering instead of redirecting. Because i only redirect after success. So how do i send the user to the ancor with

```
@method_decorator(login_required())
def post(self, request, article_id, article):
    self.object = self.get_object() # needed to fill context
    form = CommentForm(request.POST, response_to_id=article_id, author=self.request.user)  # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid():  # All validation rules pass
        comment = form.save()
        redirect_url = reverse('article_detail', kwargs={'article_id': article_id}) + "#" + str(comment.id)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)  # Redirect after POST
return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
```

the call at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the `#whatever`.

just add the `window.location.href` if form is submit,

```
<script>

{% if submit %}
window.location.href = "#whatever"
{% endif %}

</script>
```

**Note:** send the context variable of submit=True if request is POST.

and in your htm form,

```
<form id='whatever' action="some" method='post'></form>
```

Example: [Django: How to send user to ancor after POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825367/django-how-to-send-user-to-ancor-after-post/23825566#23825566)

Comment: Your example link goes to the url of this thread. I don't think that's intended.

Comment: This is just link, If you click on this it will show my answer like your form submiting.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. Thank you very much for your help. It worked!